# How would I prevent a integer from being generated more than once in a random generator

Tags: c++

I want to generate random coordinates within a chess board, with no coordinates being generated more than once. I tried making multiple counts variable to track each coordinate (eg a5, h7), however I realized creating parameters for every 64 coordinates would take some time. Is there a faster method?

```
// Declarations:
string coordinates_x[8] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"};
string coordinates_y[8] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};
vector<string> store;

// Storing coordinates in a vector:
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  for(int p = 0; p < 8; p++)
  {
    string temp = coordinates_x[p] + coordinates_y[i];
    store.push_back(temp);
  }
}

srand(time(NULL)); // integer generator intialization 

// Generating for white side of board:
for(int i = 0; i < w.size(); i++) // iterating based on the amt of chess pieces:
{
   int location_w = rand() % 31;
   cout << store[location_w] << endl;
   // Parameters to prevent the same location being outputted more than once
}
```

Comment: Generate a vector of all coordinates and then use `random_shuffle`

Comment: ^^^^^ ideally, use [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) with a decently prepared prng (such as a [std::mt19937](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine)). `std::random_shuffle` was deprecated in C++14, and is gone in C++17 and beyond.

Comment: Some low-quality RNGs (LFSRs, `pcg32_once_insecure`) can directly generate numbers without duplicates, but only for an exact size (2^n or 2^n-1). Note that using `rand() % 31` is a horrible idea, see e.g. http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a std::set. Unique objects. Or even unordered_set if there is no sorting need.

Comment: I actually dont understand how the std::set woud be applied in this situtation. Could you make a clarification or give an example?

Comment: Generate coordinates, store them in the set. Duplicates will not be stored. After you have enough items to pick from, pick one at random.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @dyukha , one solution would be to shuffle a pool of coordinates, which might end up looking something like :

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::mt19937& get_generator()
{
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 g(rd());
    return g;
}

std::vector<std::string> get_random_coords(std::vector<std::string>& pool, int num_coords) 
{
    std::shuffle(pool.begin(), pool.end(), get_generator());
    return std::vector<std::string>
        (pool.begin(), pool.begin() + std::min(num_coords, (int)pool.size()));
}

int main() 
{
    int const board_width = 8;
    int const board_height = 8;
    std::vector<std::string> store;
    std::string coordinates_x[board_width] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"};
    std::string coordinates_y[board_height] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};

    for(int y = 0; y < board_height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < board_width; x++)
        {
            store.push_back(coordinates_x[x] + coordinates_y[y]);
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::string> random_pool(store.begin(), store.end());
    for(auto const& coord : get_random_coords(random_pool, 5))
    {
        std::cout << coord << '\n';
    }
 }
```